# Move script by date and total size limit

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm kinda new to Linux and just need a script to move files from 1 location to another for my server to another server for archiving.

I currently do this manually every other day from 1 server to another that has a 400GB hard drive.

I would like to have this script search in a directory/sub dir and look for any files/folders older then 30+ days and move them. But only do 350GB a day or somehow until the 2nd server runs out of space. The archive server uploads to the cloud every day. Gdrive 750GB daily limit.

I have roughly 20TB to move and doing this manually can be a daily task which I would like to automate.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible off-topic question. Currently I don't see anything on-topic in your request, we don't support generic linux or GNU/Linux, and you didn't mention a OS that is on-topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: sorry. I am currently using Ubuntu v18.04.3 LTS